# How can I use path parameters in my connection in Sitecore Personalize?

Tags: personalization, sitecore-personalize

When i'm integrating with a connection that has a path parameter such as `GET https://api.com/products/123` How can I setup my connection in Sitecore Personalize to pass in the product Id (e.g. 123) as a dynamic variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add dynamic path parameters into a connection, add the path parameter using FreeMarker. E.g. GET [https://api.com/products/${productId}](https://api.com/products/$%7BproductId%7D)

An example is shown in the screen shot below

[image]

**Path parameters and Decision Models**

If you are using a Data System in a decision model, the path parameter can be passed in the request from the output of programmable or a decision table.
Steps:

1. Connect your programmable or decision to the Data System.

[image]

2. Setup your programmable or decision table to output the required parameter.

Below is an example of a decision table setting the product_id based
on the city of the guest.

[image]

3. Open your data system and enter the name of your output as the request input for your path parameter. When you start entering the name of your output, typeahead will appear based on the programmable/decision table connected to your data system.

Below is an example of the product_id being set from the output a decision table.

[image]

When your decision model runs the path parameter will now be passed in as an input from the programmable or decision table. The response from the data system can now be used for further decisioning or personalization.